# QlikView Default selection trigger - previous + current year minus current month

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I want to create a sheet trigger to select the previous year and the current year but not the current month.

If for example we were in 201604...

Sample data is as follows:

```
201511

201512

201601

201602

201603

201604
```

Selection I would want would be:

```
201511

201512

201601

201602

201603
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Trigger expression you can use the `YearStart` function along with the `MAX` function to get all of the previous year plus the current years months excluding the current month.

```
='<' & Max(YearMonth) & '>=' & Num#(Date(YearStart(Max(Date#(YearMonth, 'YYYYMM')), -1), 'YYYYMM'), '##')
```